# Did i make Composition right in Java?

Tags: java, php, composition

So, i just had a seminar where i had to present a Sale Program, for this presentation he asked for Assossiation, Composition, and agregation. The thing is, since i know barely anything of POO i find PHP really difficult to understand and read, so I decided to do it in Java, and He said that there were no Composition in the following code:

```
package Loja_produtos_escolares;

import java.util.*;

public class SaleItem {
    private double salePrice;
    private int amount;
    private float discount;
    private double iTotal;
    private Product produto;

    public SaleItem(Product produto, int amount, int d) {
        this.produto = produto;
        this.salePrice = produto.price;
        this.amount = amount;

        discount = (float) d / 100;

        double fdisc;
        double itenSoma;
        itenSoma = amount * salePrice;
        fdisc = (amount * salePrice) * discount;
        iTotal = (amount * salePrice) - fdisc;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return produto.unity;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return iTotal;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public float getDiscount() {
        return discount = discount * 100;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "produto: " + produto;
    }

    public double getOriginalPrice() {
        return produto.price;

    }
```

then the supposedly composition

```
package Loja_produtos_escolares;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class Sale {
    public Date data;
    public SimpleDateFormat dataformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    public double total;
    public String obs;
    public Customer cliente;
    private int protocolo;
    private int qntProt = 1000000;
    private String output;
    boolean cfp  = true;

    ArrayList<SaleItem> listaP = new ArrayList<SaleItem>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Estabelecendo A composição entre Sale e SaleItem
    public void addSaleItem(Product produto) {
        
        Product prod = produto;
        int qntd, desc;

        System.out.println("Insira a quantidade: ");
        qntd = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Insira o desconto:  [ obs: Não utilize \"%\" (porcentagem)!!! ]");
        desc = input.nextInt();

        SaleItem item = new SaleItem(prod, qntd, desc);
        listaP.add(item);
    }
```

I used some examples but STILL, I'm not sure i completely understand those three.

(i do have some examples, but i'm not sure i should put it here)

I've tried to follow my friend's example, and as far as I understando PHP, i did 'basically' the same stuff

```
 class ItemVenda {

        // Definindo os atributos
        public $precoVenda;
        public $quantidade;
        public $desconto;
        public $total;
        public $produto;
        
        // Estabelecendo a associação entre a classe ItemVenda e a classe Produto
        public function setProduto(Produto $produto) {
            return $this -> produto = $produto;
        }

    }
```

then the composition

```
 class Venda {

        // Definindo os atributos
        private $id;
        private $data;
        private $total;
        private $obs;
        private $vendas;
        private $cliente;

        // Definindo o construtor
        public function __construct($obs,$id){
            $this -> id = $id;
            $this -> data = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $this -> total = 0; 
            $this -> obs = $obs;
        }
       
        // Estabelecendo a composição entre a classe Venda e a classe ItemVenda
        public function addItemVenda( $quantidade, $desconto, $produto) {

            // Atribuindo dados aos atributos de um novo itemVenda
            $precoVenda = $produto -> precoVenda;
            $itemVenda = new ItemVenda;
            $itemVenda -> quantidade = $quantidade;
            $itemVenda -> precoVenda = $precoVenda * $quantidade;
            $itemVenda -> desconto = $desconto / 100;
            $itemVenda -> total = $itemVenda -> precoVenda - ($itemVenda -> precoVenda * $itemVenda -> desconto);
            $itemVenda -> produto = $itemVenda -> setProduto($produto);
            $this -> vendas[] = $itemVenda;
        }
```

Comment: The `Product` field in `SaleItem` looks like composition to me.

Comment: that was supposed to be an association. I created a Product class, where i instantiated a few Product obj. then On Sale class, is composed of SaleItem, which is an association of Products. do you think I need to share the Product code?